# abstract class naming convention

Tags: java, coding-style

Should we have a team coding standard that the names of abstract classes have prefix `Abstract` ? e.g.

```
public abstract class AbstractB implements B {}
```

Comment: I'm betting this question gets closed. It's very subjective. I vote yes, though.

Comment: But should your interface B not be called InterfaceB by the same standard

Comment: @bstick: Nooooo! Interfaces are types. Name them what they are!

Comment: @Ryan Stewart I was being a little tongue in cheek.

Comment: @bstick: Yeah, well someone will take you seriously :p

Comment: I didn't think it was subjective

Comment: Don't use class name prefixes. A class name show describe it's functionality or responsibility. I'll show you why.

Given an interface Abba
And an implementation AbstractAbba
When we change the interface to a class
Then we have to rename AbstractAbba to something else

This is now a scenario I want to end up in; changing the name of one class because I changed another entity.

Comment: A lot of in programming is about subjectivity. Code is for people not for machines. So why close these quesions? I find them extremely useful. How do the majority perceive the subject ...

Comment: Eugene, I would even go as far as saying _everything_ is subjective, if not dependent on something. When will we ever be able to give 1 definitively and universally true and correct answer? This would be the exception, not the norm. Frequently my googling takes me to very useful questions and answers, only to find them having been closed. To me, it's quite obvious that StackOverflow failed in this regard, and I would argue, this closing fetishism it is of no benefit to the community. Instead, it will foster elitism and drive the success of competitors such as Quora.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Yes, in fact if you look at the javadocs of the standard library at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ you'll find that the list of classes in the bottom-left frame begins with abstract classes using the naming convention you have mentioned in your question.

```
AbstractAction
AbstractAnnotationValueVisitor6
AbstractBorder
AbstractButton
AbstractCellEditor
AbstractCollection
AbstractColorChooserPanel
AbstractDocument
AbstractDocument.AttributeContext
AbstractDocument.Content
AbstractDocument.ElementEdit
AbstractElementVisitor6
AbstractExecutorService
AbstractInterruptibleChannel
AbstractLayoutCache
AbstractLayoutCache.NodeDimensions
AbstractList
AbstractListModel
AbstractMap
AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry
AbstractMarshallerImpl
AbstractMethodError
AbstractOwnableSynchronizer
AbstractPreferences
AbstractProcessor
AbstractQueue
AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
AbstractScriptEngine
AbstractSelectableChannel
AbstractSelectionKey
AbstractSelector
AbstractSequentialList
AbstractSet
AbstractSpinnerModel
AbstractTableModel
AbstractTypeVisitor6
AbstractUndoableEdit
AbstractUnmarshallerImpl
AbstractWriter
```

Take any one of them, say the first one, and check its definition: `AbstractAction`. It indeed implements `Action` which is again similar to your convention. It's subclasses are named like: `ClosedAction`, `MaximizeAction`, etc.

Comment: counter example: java.util.Calendar

Comment: @ Susam Pal - So, abstract class without implementing interface should start with 'Abstract' ! Note: Calander is an abstract class

Comment: I'm not sure `AbstractMethodError` applies here.

Answer (score 12):

Generally any kind of standard is a good thing in a team setting.
Otherwise team members might name classes in such a way that only they understand and then you could get a mix of people's different coding styles which leads to confusion.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. I would prefer to name them with the Abstract prefix, but the most important thing is follow the team / project coding style.

Answer (score 5):

For Readability it does sound like a good idea. When reading code you will be able to know right away what the class is. As long as everyone follows the standard it is good.

Answer (score 4):

I won't say yay or nay in an answer, but whatever you choose, use a good [static analysis tool](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/naming.html#AbstractNaming) to ensure it.

Answer (score 3):

Modern IDEs will pop up descriptive text when you hover over an object.  Prefixing is redundant in this case.

Comment: which requires javadocs, a whole 'nother thing for a team to fight coding-style battles over.

Answer (score 2):

As with most questions of this type: "it depends".  I like consistency and clarity, so if it works for you and your shop, great.  However, if you have legacy Abstract classes, you would then want to go back and refactor them to the same naming convention.